# Find all x in Z8 satisfying [2]x+[4]=[2]

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I found that [2] mod 8 is (...-22,-14,-6,2,10,18,26...)
and that [4] mod 8 is (...-20,-12,-4,4,12,20,28...)
But I can't find any x number from mod 8 that satisfies [2]x+[4]=[2]
Does that mean that there isn't any number or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What about $x=[3]$ and $x=[7]$?

Comment: Yeah I didn't know I had to do them to in order to solve the question, but I got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2x+4\equiv 2$$
Subtract $4$ from each side
$$2x\equiv -2\equiv 6\pmod{8}$$
We can divide both sides by $2$, provided we also divide the modulus by $2$, getting
$$x\equiv 3\pmod{4}$$
Hence, modulo $8$, the two solutions are $x\equiv 3$ and $x\equiv 7$.